# Unhandled exception of type System.TypeInitializationException occured in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I created this topic as I could not find the answer even though there are many similar threads.

Recently many users reported that the tool created in Visual Studio stopped working. This is a WPF application written in C# and its purpose is to pick up Excel spreadsheets and export them to Oracle database for further calculations.

The application crashes when it attempts to create a class `OracleBulkCopy` which is a member of `Oracle.DataAccess` library (it is added to the project as Reference). The project was distributed among users as installation package and the idea was that they do not need to install anything else.

Currently I am investigating this issue on 3 machines:

- 1 - my regular laptop
- 2 - virtual machine set up on my laptop
- 3 - old laptop delivered by my colleague

It works well only on machine no 3 which has reinstalled Windows 7 64-bit and Oracle Client 11g (Oracle.DataAccess version 2.112.2.0). The other two also run on Windows 7 64-bit, we performed tests on various Oracle libraries. Machine number 1 is a bit messy as I removed or reinstalled many versions of DataAccess and in GAC they are all visible. I tried to setup machine no 2 (virtual machine, also fresh Windows 7) the same way as machine no 3 but the application still crashes.

Here is the error message and my findings after browsing some forums and StackOverflow questions.

[image: <photo1>]

1. I found some information about `InnerException` which I caught with try...catch. The description is as below:

> Inner Exception
>
> Step into: Stepping over property 'System.Exception.get_InnerException'.  To step into properties, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
>   Step into: Stepping over property 'System.Exception.get_InnerException'.  To step into properties, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
>   Step into: Stepping over property 'System.TypeLoadException.get_Message'.  To step into properties, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
>   Step into: Stepping over property 'System.Console.get_Out'.  To step into properties, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
>   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility(String version)
>   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
>   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The library `OraOps11w` (different version in fact) is available in the folder where Oracle Client was installed. I checked PATH system variables for each machine and they clearly point the right paths.

2. GAC looks different in 3 cases. Laptop 1 shows total mess – as I mentioned earlier result of numerous re-installations. Laptop 3 (the old one which works fine) shows just 1 entry for Oracle.DataAcces and 2 Policy records. Laptop no 2 also shows the same libraries as laptop 3 but it does not work. I wanted to edit GAC lists but unfortunately due to lack of admin rights I am not able to do that either manually or with `Gacutil.exe`. If this may fix the problem the only option is to install the package with correct libraries.
3. I also found a tutorial which suggests unloading the project and editing `csproj`. I corrected some values but this also did not bring the expected result.
4. One discussion mentioned that faulty class may have static constructors but `OracleBulkCopy` does not have any static elements.

[image: OracleBulkCopy class]

I am running out of ideas how this can be fixed. Have someone of you faced similar issue and managed overcome the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The actual error message is this:

> Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found.

I guess the issue is with the Oracle client tools not being installed correctly, or with the wrong bits (32/64). This is a very common problem with ODP.NET and the Oracle client tools and they are sometimes hard to diagnose.

Install the same version of ODP.NET among all machines with the right bits for your machine should work.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for quick answer. Are you sure that OracleBulkCopy is available in the latest Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library? I downloaded 4.121.2 and I cannot see it at my end. From my point of view it looks like OracleBulkCopy is not supported by this class.

http://banner.tbr.edu/E50529_01/ODPNT/intro004.htm

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I read it was available already... Still there is a version problem, so install the same version of ODP.NET among all machines with the right bits for your machine and it should work.

Comment: I noticed one interesting thing. I installed Visual Studio Enterprise (I think it is former Express version) on my virtual machine and the solution works. When I launch it as installed application it does not work. Do you have any ideas what may be the difference between these 2 apps?

Comment: Bits. Visual Studio is 32 bits. Your machine probably 64 and your program uses that.